# How to rearrange repeater automatically in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm create the UI that display data from SQL Server using repeater in VB.Net and Bootstrap.
I have 5 repeaters that display different data.
I want to make the repeaters shown like this:

[image]

The repeaters will automatically rearrange if the data is added or removed.
If the data from database is added or removed, I want the display is become something like this:

[image]

I've try this code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr1" runat="server"> 
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3>Repeater 1</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <ul class="dashboard-list">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field1") %></a></strong><br>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field2") %></a></strong><br>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr2" runat="server"> 
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3>Repeater 2</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <ul class="dashboard-list">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field1") %></a></strong><br>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field2") %></a></strong><br>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr3" runat="server"> 
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3>Repeater 3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <ul class="dashboard-list">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field1") %></a></strong><br>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field2") %></a></strong><br>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr4" runat="server"> 
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3>Repeater 4</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <ul class="dashboard-list">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field1") %></a></strong><br>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field2") %></a></strong><br>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr5" runat="server"> 
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3>Repeater 5</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <ul class="dashboard-list">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field1") %></a></strong><br>
                <strong><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field2") %></a></strong><br>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ div>
```

But its displayed like this:

[image]

How can I make the display shown like the first image?